# File.Move throws error when used with BackgroundWorkerr in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, backgroundworker

### Solved

> I figured out that the GetNewFolderNameBasedOnDate method internally didn't close the file. I have that method fixed and it working normal now

I am trying to move selected files from one folder to another using BackgroundWorker process in C#. Here is my DoWork() method that determine whether to move the files or just copy. My File.Move() throws an exception that "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I tried different methods as mentioned in the threads here in stackoverflow.

```
private void FileProcessor_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Copy files
    long bytes = 0;
    string destSubFolder = String.Empty;
    string destFile = string.Empty;
    foreach (FileInfo file in oSettings.SourceFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(OnChange, new object[] { new UIProgress(file.Name, bytes, oSettings.MaxBytes) });

            destSubFolder = GetNewFolderNameBasedOnDate(file);
                    
            //Create a new subfolder under the current active folder
            string newPath = Path.Combine(oSettings.TargetFolder, destSubFolder);
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            destFile = Path.Combine(oSettings.TargetFolder, destSubFolder, file.Name);

            if (chkDeleteSourceFiles.Checked)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file.FullName);

                if (f.Exists)
                {
                    File.Move(file.FullName, destFile);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(file.FullName, destFile, true);
            }

            //Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UIError err = new UIError(ex, file.FullName);
            this.Invoke(OnError, new object[] { err });
            if (err.result == DialogResult.Cancel) break;
        }
        bytes += file.Length;
    }
}
```

I tried to delete the files in "RunWorkerCompleted" method too. But didn't resolve the problem. This fails when it tries to delete the last file in the list.

```
private void FileProcessor_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Operation completed, update UI
    ChangeUI(false);

    foreach (FileInfo file in oSettings.SourceFiles)
    {
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

GetNewFolderNameBasedOnDate() calls GetDateTaken() which was the culprit. Earlier I didn't use FileStream object but used `Image myImage = Image.FromFile(filename);` I didn't know that Image.FromFile locks the file.

```
private DateTime GetDateTaken(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Image myImage = Image.FromStream(fs);
            PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);
            DateTime dtaken;

            //Convert date taken metadata to a DateTime object
            string sdate = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value).Trim();
            string secondhalf = sdate.Substring(sdate.IndexOf(" "), (sdate.Length - sdate.IndexOf(" ")));
            string firsthalf = sdate.Substring(0, 10);
            firsthalf = firsthalf.Replace(":", "-");
            sdate = firsthalf + secondhalf;
            dtaken = DateTime.Parse(sdate);
            return dtaken;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to ask the obvious -- can you move/delete the files when your process isn't running?

Comment: And without the Backgroundworker (ie without a thread) ?  Just call DoWork() from a BtnClick to test.

Comment: I would suggest download Process Monitor and see if process has a file open handle on the file.

Comment: Something need a further investigation, File.Move cannot overwrite a file that exist in the destination directory, and chkDeleteSourceFiles is a UI checkbox?

Comment: If you're moving the files when delete file is checked, why are you trying to delete the source files in RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: What are you doing in the Progress handler, I notice you are passing along the file name.  If you do something in there with the file, you run the risk of the file being in use when the Move occurs

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I went through the code again based on your comments to see if I can zero down on the problem. I figured out that the `GetNewFolderNameBasedOnDate` method internally didn't close the file. I have that method fixed and it working normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new FileInfo objects, keep it simple and re-use the same one. I suspect the problem is that you have multiple references to the same file in your code, which prevents it from being removed. Try something like this to move it:

```
if (chkDeleteSourceFiles.Checked)
{
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        file.MoveTo(destFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiple FileInfos for the same file does not cause file-in-use problems.

Comment: @Peter you're right, I should have tried that before I posted the answer. It's still ugly, but it's probably not the cause of the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is the BeginInvoke call to OnChange and the new UIProgress() object that is holding onto the file.  Does UIProgress open the file?  You could try just using Invoke() and see if that helps.